# User Preferences Flutter Management

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, riverpod

I am developing an app with Flutter in which the user preferences affect the UI, for instance the user preferred metric system affects how measure are shown by converting to kg or lbs.

I was curious on how you would implement a retrieval method for the user preferences in a way that:

- allows synchrounous access to the user preferences in code (having to call and await the getUserPreferences every time just to map entities to viewmodels according to the user preferences in the UI is bothersome)
- allows to synchronize the UI to the changes in the stored User Preferences

I am using Riverpod and the closest solution that came to my mind is to use a Stream to get the User Preferences and watch it in the main, above the MaterialApp Widget, so that I can access the UserPreferences value as below.

Main:

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    return _UserEagerInitialization(
        child: MaterialApp.router(
      locale: context.locale,
      builder: (context, widget) =>
          responsiveAppBuilder.defineDevicesScreenWidth(widget!),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'App',
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      theme: AppTheme.themeData,
      routerConfig: router,
    ));
  }
}

class _UserEagerInitialization extends ConsumerWidget {
  const _UserEagerInitialization({required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final userAuthenticationStream =
        ref.watch(getUserAuthenticationStatusProvider);
    final userPreferencesStream = ref.watch(getUserPreferencesProvider);
    final userProfileStream = ref.watch(getUserProfileProvider);

    return userAuthenticationStream.maybeWhen(
        data: (userSession) => userPreferencesStream.maybeWhen(
            data: (userPreferences) => userProfileStream.maybeWhen(
                data: (userProfile) => child,
                orElse: () => const LoadingSpinner(),
                skipLoadingOnRefresh: true,
                skipLoadingOnReload: true),
            orElse: () => const LoadingSpinner(),
            skipLoadingOnRefresh: true,
            skipLoadingOnReload: true),
        orElse: () => const LoadingSpinner(),
        skipLoadingOnRefresh: true,
        skipLoadingOnReload: true);
  }
}
```

Accessing User Preferences synchrounously somewhere else:

```
ref.watch(getUserPreferencesProvider).requireValue
```

Why do I want to change?

- Using **requireValue** could be error prone
- Updating the whole MaterialApp widget with a change of the UserSettings might be an overkill (though documentation claims that it won't this rebuild the entire application when the provider changes)

Documentation used for the above approach:
https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/eager_initialization

Comment: Do you need those preferences to be persistent and be saved between user sessions?

Comment: They are persisted in a DB from which I already retrieve the data. Best approach looks like to retrieve that data on startup and access it whenever needed.

Comment: Your code does not comply with the eager initialization approach indicated by the Riverpod docs, it is actually building an instance of `MaterialApp` inside the build method of `MyApp` when the provider gets data. In addition, why is your provider returning a stream?

Comment: You are right, I updated the above code accordingly. What do you mean with "why is your provider returning a stream?"? userPreferencesStream is a Streamprovider that listens a Stream from the local DB getting the UserPreferences. I'm using a stream as I don't need to refresh or notifyListeners in case of change of UserPreferences.

Comment: By definition a stream is asynchronous, there is no workaround for that. If you want to have access to the current value, you could use a BehaviorSubject which exposes synchronously the last value inserted in the stream... but Riverpod does not allow having a BehaviorSubject, just plain streams

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do then apps developed in flutter access the current value of the user preferences and update without any waiting delay? Should I just go for my solution of eager initialisation in the main?

Comment: You are mixing two concepts here:  
* Eager initialization is just a solution for initializing the value of a provider before it is actually used by any widget, since **providers are lazy**.  
* Having streams and asynchronous operations.
I your case, even if you do the eager initialization trick you will still have to deal with the fact that the provided objects are streams, and have you UI handle that. It's an architecture problem, which is different from your original question.

Comment: In my above solution the stream value can be synchronously accessed with the riverpod method ".requireValue" that makes it possible in conjunction with the eager initialization. Why would you define this an architecture problem? Can you give me some sources I can refer to check how to handle it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, `requireValue` will indeed work if you have eagerly initialized your provider. But you will still have the asynchronous aspect in your `_UserEagerInitialization` widget. The architecture problem is to your question "_How do then apps developed in flutter access the current value ..._", which does not have a simple answer.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out @pcba-dev
Can you please link me some architecture examples/sources on the above question?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe take a look at this tutorial: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/key-value

It is a tutorial from flutter that uses the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package. It is only usable if you store small values (it was made for small preferences), and may remove the need to store these values in your database, but if you want to track those preferences with your database, this is not what you need. In this case, maybe a splash screen could do the trick ?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question. I am already storing the userPreferences in a local DB and retrieving them with a stream.